# def compose[A,B,C](f: B => C, g: A => B): A => C = {f(g(_))} is noty valid scala declaration?

Tags: scala

I am new to scala this might be a cake walk concept but trying to understand   why

```
def compose[A,B,C](f: B => C, g: A => B): A => C = {f(g(_))}
```

Is not valid scala declation?

Comment: i also tried this
def compose[A,B,C](f: B => C, g: A => B): A => C = {f(g(_: A))}
It still gives error

Comment: what is the error can you update the question by clicking the edit below the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `f(g(_))` means `f(x => g(x))` in Scala, not `x => f(g(x))`.

Comment: Thanks Alexey this reasoning actually makes sense

Comment: The rules are, approximately, that it extends to the closest `()` (or `{}`, or `=` if that's the entire definition) which contain anything more than `_` itself (so not `g(x => x)`).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
def compose[A,B,C](f: B => C, g: A => B): A => C = { a: A => f(g(a)) }
```

The underscore-as-placeholder syntax works inconsistently, and in particular doesn't tend to work in nested function calls like you have here. A good rule of thumb is that if the underscore syntax is erroring, try expanding it to an explicit lambda and see if it works then.

Comment: I know this works only wanted to know y above is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a name to the variable that receives your function g:

```
def compose[A,B,C](f: B => C, g: A => B): A => C = {x => f(g(x))}
```

You can also do as follows (i renamed the function name to make it clear that is a differente thing) :

```
def myCompose[A,B,C](f: B => C, g: A => B): A => C = f compose g
```